# Client side check on video duration limit with javascript or jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, video

Hi All Client side experts
I would like to ask a fairly simple question here
I am trying to make a site where users can upload videos which will be directly uploaded to S3 Amazon account.
But I want to limit these videos to 3 minutes in length before user uploads it.
I googled alot but didn't find any solution .
Any one ever did this please help me
P.S my site is using HTML5, CSS3 Jquery as front end.. C# WCF REST service for back end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with HTML 5 Video and file API.

```
<video
    id="video-active"
    width="0"
    height="0">
    <source src="file:///C:/Users/Joshua/Desktop/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

var time = $('#video-active').currentTime;
```

Maybe this way, but I have never done something like this before. 
[More Information](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)

Comment: So you think I should give the uploading file path to source tag, then try to get the current time?